# Storing information in a database on a Heroku server

Tags: database, facebook, sqlite, heroku

I'm trying to make a facebook application that stores some user data in a database. What kind of databases can I use if I'm using Heroku? Can I use SQLite?

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is the one database you can't use.

Heroku will give you a 5Mb Postgres database for free with your application (assuming it's a rails application). There are addon providers for mySQL, Redis etc or you're free to connect to you own database outside of Heroku but beware of the latency that you will experience.